# In rotational motion, why $a = rα$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, torque, rotational-kinematics

The formula of torque is given by $$τ= F*r = Iα,$$ while solving some questions I came across a question of rotating pulley where these two formulas were equated to find value of $α$. How $a=rα$? a here is linear acceleration, α is the angular acceleration, τ is the Torque produced by force F, and r is the perpendicular distance from axis of rotation, I is the moment of inertia.

Comment: Do you understand why $v=R\omega$ or $L=R\theta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not always true but in case of pure rolling

consider a figure
[image: Pure rolling]

In case of pure rolling suppose the rim of ring moves a distance x  corresponding the ring covers an angle $ \theta$

$$X=R\theta$$

On differentiating

$$dx/dt =R \omega$$
Hence $R\omega$

Further differentiating

$$dv/dt =R \alpha$$
Hence $a=R\alpha$

Comment: If viewed from the center of mass, this analysis would apply to a rotating pulley.

Comment: @R.W.Bird I think it would work for a wheel translating and I have specified pure rolling

Comment: The question is about a rotating pulley.

Comment: @R.W.Bird dont worry would be valid there also  and 1st you were arguing that it would be valid for a rotating pulley . Take a chill pill man

Comment: Suppose the force provided is due to tension, will this formula be same if there is slipping between the rope and the rotating pulley?

Comment: @AnshumanBharadwaj in case of slipping this is not valid since tension in both the sides of string will be same so net torque will be 0 then you can use T-mg=ma these normal expressions

Answer (score -1):

a=rα as i understand gives the acceleration of a single point with angular acceleration α and the distance from axis as r.
As we know that I is of a point from the axis is defined as mr^2 where r is the perpendicular distance from the axis of rotation. Also we know that F=ma

Using this and the equation τ=F∗r=Iα we can easily prove a=rα

We have to keep in mind that a here stands for tangential acceleration provided by the rotational motion of the point object.